# URL types with multiple bundle identifier for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, url-scheme

I'd like my iOS project to handle multiple URL types and multiple bundle identifiers, so I can install 2 versions of the app on the same device.

I have 2 different bundle IDs: com.mycompany.myapp and com.mycompany.myapp-test

I'm registering 2 URL types for both bundle identifiers in the Info.plist file

[image]

I generate 2 builds with the 2 bundle identifiers and installing both apps on the same device. Then I'm trying to reach my apps using 2 urls: myapp://feed and myapp-test://feed.

However for some reason, I cannot open myapp-test and it always opens myapp when I click on both links.

There is certainly something wrong in the way I handle this so I'm wondering how I can manage multiple bundle ID with multiple URL scheme within the same Xcode project?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm experiencing the exact same thing.

Comment: You cannot build all the URL types in the same bundle otherwise it will be opened for all of them. The schema should be different for each bundle, e.g. variable like $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER). In my tests it didn't work though. Still trying.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of investigation produced a few solutions.

### Automatic

Use `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` for both identifier and scheme then open each app using URL like `com.mycompany.myapp://`. This will always work regardless on how many targets, schemes or build settings you have.

### Semi-automatic

Set user-defined variables. You need to put these variables in your `info.plist` file in order to reference them. This approach is more flexible but you have to write the scheme names by hand (only once). Actually it's the way I chosen in my applications.

### By hand

This is more a workaround than a proper solution but 100% works in all cases: set identifier and scheme before build each bundle.

For example if you have identifier/scheme pairs like `com.mycompany.myapp/myapp` and `com.mycompany.myapp-test/myapp-test` then do the following:

1. Set identifier `com.mycompany.myapp` and scheme `myapp` then build app bundle `myapp`
2. Set idientifier `com.mycompany.myapp-test` and scheme `myapp-test` then build app bundle `myapp-test`

This way you should be able to open each bundle calling the relative scheme. Though you will need to change the URL types before each build. Personally I would never do like this.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that:

1) for app with `com.mycompany.myapp` bundle ID you registered `mayapp` schema, there should be no `myapp-test` schema registered;

same time,

2) for app with `com.mycompany.myapp-test` bundle ID you registered `myapp-test` schema, there should be no `myapp` schema registered.

If I've got the problem correctly, the reason of such a behavior is both your apps are registered for both schemes. When you try to open some URL (myapp-test://... or myapp://... ) iOS detects that there is more then one app registered and picks first to handle it.

It's not needed to register schemes that you intended to open - you need to register schemes you're going to handle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have double checked that I don't have any duplicate schemas anywhere as per the answer from Igor B. No matter what I do, my test widget still tries to open links in the main app, not the test app. 

Are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What I did (in Xcode 12), partially based on the input from @clamiax

Targets -> Your App -> Build Settings -> + -> Add User-Defined setting ->

Setting: `URL_SCHEME`

Value: `yourapp-debug`, `yourapp`, `yourapp-test` etc. for different schemes.

Targets -> Your App -> Info -> URL Types

URL Schemes: `$(URL_SCHEME)`

[image: define value]
[image: use value]

Answer (score 0):

I created config files for each env then I created identifier and schema variables there and then used them in the url identifier and scheme worked like a charm.

[great tutorial for configuring env with config files](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-set-up-ios-environments/)

[image]