# How do you configure multiple iOS URL Schemes

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Is it possible to register multiple URL schemes that are associated with different app ids for the same app. For example I have separate apps per environment of my application each with their own unique bundke id. E.G

```
com.test.app-dev (testapp-dev://)
com.test.app-qa (testapp-qa://)
com.test.app (testapp://)
```

If I want to launch the dev app from a url, I would use want to use testapp-dev://

Comment: If the apps have different bundle ids then they are different apps. You need to include the appropriate info.plist entry for each app. This is something you would need to manage during build.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on this. I was able to execute a custom script in a post build action in the XCode Schemes that I have for each environment that uses plist buddy to update the Info.plist file in the built products directory.

Comment: I answered this on another question [Answer - config files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961124/2704776)

Answer (score 2):

What I did (in Xcode 12)

Targets -> Your App -> Build Settings -> + -> Add User-Defined setting ->

Setting: `URL_SCHEME`

Value: `yourapp-debug`, `yourapp`, `yourapp-test` etc. for different schemes.

Targets -> Your App -> Info -> URL Types

URL Schemes: `$(URL_SCHEME)`

[image: define value]
[image: use value]

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulw11 suggested this needed to be done at build time. For each application environment, I have an associated Xcode Scheme. In the build section of the xcode shceme, you can configure a postbuild action. You can execute a shell script as a post build action.

So for example in the **com.test.app-dev** scheme, there is a post build action that runs this script

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :CFBundleURLTypes:0:CFBundleURLSchemes:0 testapp-dev" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :CFBundleURLTypes:0:CFBundleURLName com.test.app-dev" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
```

Then in the **com.test.app-qa** scheme, there is a post build action that runs this script:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :CFBundleURLTypes:0:CFBundleURLSchemes:0 testapp-qa" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :CFBundleURLTypes:0:CFBundleURLName com.test.app-qa" "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
```

This ensures that the right custom url scheme is registered per application associated with each environment.

Answer (score 0):

(in Xcode 15.2) What I did and working well

1. Targets -> Your App -> Build Settings -> (+) Add User-Defined setting ->
2. setting: "URL_SCHEME".
   Value: xxx-debug, xxx, xxx-test etc. (noted: for different schemes)

Targets -> Your App -> Info -> URL Types

Idendentifier: $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
URL Schemes: $(URL_SCHEME)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qFU9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucMn0.png)

Comment: Thank you for helping users on stackoverflow. This answer looks like a duplicate from Esben von Buchwald's answer. If you think it gives more information or value, than mention what the difference is.

Comment: you can say that but my answer is from my real project and it works well with my latest.