# How to register different URL Scheme for each app configuration (Debug, Release, ..etc)?

Tags: xcode, url-scheme

So I have two URL Schemes that look like this `myapp:\\` and `myapp-dev:\\` that I added under `{MyTarget} > Info > URL Types` and I need each one of them to open the corresponding app (first one for release and the other for debug). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok here's how to do it:

1. Select your target > Build Settings > The + button > "Add User-Defined Setting"

[image]

2. Give it a name (let's call it "APP_URL_SCHEME") and then click on the arrow at its left to expand the "Debug" and "Release" options and add both your URL schemes in place

[image]

3. Now go to the "info" tab, expand the URL Types and click on the + button below it to add a new one then use the setting we just defined as the URL Schemes like this $(APP_URL_SCHEME)

[image]

Comment: I guess the identifier should be added as well as a variable in case the user is using different ones.

Comment: to expand on the comment by @AlejandroL.Rocha, i believe this is done as described in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65567260/12197001
which says to set the identifier to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`. dont set the URL Scheme as suggested, as a better way is shown in the original comment here.
but setting the identifier to `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` should set the correct identifier for the build variant.